# Windows Phone 8, minimize app

Tags: windows-phone-8

Have a broblem with minimize application, when back button pressed:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I need do not close application, just minimize him to background, have any idea for this?

Answer (score 2):

You *should* close on back - otherwise you will fail certification for the store. If you need a background task running, instead use a [Background Agent](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Background-Agent-Sample-02f0087b)

Answer (score 0):

More precise:
You can activate fast resume in the manifest:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj735579(v=vs.105).aspx

This will keep the instance of your app in the memory until the system cleans up the oldest apps to free memory when needed.

This is the recommended behavior and the default for all 8.1 Runtime Apps.

Hint:
Once put to the background, you app will still be suspended and no longer active.
It will be resumed once it gets back to the foreground.